# static_cast<T&&> and static_cast<const T&>

Tags: c++, casting, reference

I would like to ask about converting types to `T&&` and `const T&`.

```
int&& ref = static_cast<int&&>(1); // will ref assign to free memory? or
const int& ref = static_cast<const int&>(1);
```

```
int&& func() {
    return 1;
}
// or
int&& func() { // call of this function always return free memory? 
    return static_cast<int&&>(1);
}
```

```
// does static_cast<> have some different forms from casting int() (int) ?
static_cast<int&&>(1),
static_cast<const int&>(1),
or func(); // do I understand right, reference destroys with object after ';' or it returns free memory?
```

Comment: Are you taking a test right now? Otherwise, just try it out with a good compiler with all the bells and whistles turned on, and it will tell you

Comment: You have asked this question yesterday.

Comment: ... ok, so most probably not taking a test right now I guess ...

Comment: what do you mean with "free memory" ?

Comment: How is this different from the quesiton you asked yesterday?

Comment: Language is unclear; I suggest asking questions in text, not in comments. And separating code samples as much as possible to clarify.

Comment: Enabling compile warnings, my compiler told me which functions are returning a reference to a local temporary object. Also from your similar previous question, it should be noted that `std::move` does not itself move anything.  It only *allows* the object to be moved (such as by a move-constructor or a move-assignment).

Comment: It's good to be curious, but I bet you will never find a use case for `int&& i = 1;`, so figuring out if it works or not seems wasted. Perhaps the answer could be "Who cares?".

Answer (score 5):

Both versions of `func()` return dangling references. (This what you called "free memory".)

The two `ref` variables are not dangling.

You'd think that `int &&x = 1;` would dangle, but references extend lifetimes of temporary objects they're bound to. Normally this only works when the reference binds directly to the temporary, but [there's a rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) that binding through a cast also does this.

The temporary lifetime extension mechanism is little-known, so I would avoid it in the real world. *Especially* when your reference doesn't bind to a temporary directly, because [not all compilers implement that correctly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwAcpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQSAOykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCVzJdpgOWUIETMQEOT5%2BgbaY9sUMjc0EpVGx8Um2TS1teZ0KE4PhwxWj1QCUtqhexMjsHOYAzOHI3lgA1CZ7bk6zxJis59gmGgCCj0/XXg4nL88miVbPJ0BJ3CBBOADcxF5MOd/k8gScAH5PCArM5/WboEAoDag85uPHgyGYM4XAlgXYAVjcDHJMN%2BABFXgy6T9nl4MkYvnDzvSviYKRYuPzGXtYa8QScWExwiimX9XvD%2BVYBVKAJ5xAD6XgY7Mw6GFwpOaAYsy%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%2BK8BYFW1ioAxgAUPnBZFsXHf4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdR3d0DGDCMFBrGsfRI8JyA1lQFJegdoaMR5UwvssMwNBOIaAHU7aH4f/fi60htF9BDBgob4mIEgFF4Fal9qzBm5RVJDCiVh2AAcTcNwuh6LIXHwqY/Ax0IFnKSo9EKTIBGvp/0hfhghgf5Yz91ho5hvwxrUeoAh%2BgtG/iMKo4wBhAJgRA%2B%2BUCJBrAUL9bYyDMYcEeqQZ6r13rH1PnrLQKw1gIFuFgBIO9waBH7IkSQiQAhmEkFwfykh/IUjMOzIIYdsakCThSYmuC1741sETEmFsyaUwgEgHEKReoMwgEzWm9BiCRAPpwVQAQLRDQtJIE4wBkD5nZv2QGepCAkFqnoPOwhRDiGLtYsuahcZV13mUdRHACEnFkb1XgAto4pGTpg7BQi8YeJPl43qciCC8CIaDUgZCmAUMoHdLGvB%2BGCNxu9DgBMxGxJIaQah/l%2BwaApBw6o/kAgw3RgEDQ0gw57Bxu7LJMTSakHJlAKRSAlEswUd0lRKAa5sxRsTLmPNM7C1Fs9CWdBpaEwgHLd2aslYq1IEsjWWsdYOBWYbRgBATZm1xlbE6ttaD2xWc7QwwA3avXwF7RwPtcb%2B0DgdXGodcYRyjjHDAwcYnEEToE1OTB07jOzlM3g1iC52OkA4pQTjK7%2BH0JcuufcbAfO3q3duWRO7dz2PSXuVh%2B6DxHmPEek9o5D1nvPNyi9iDLxmmvVatLN7otcfvNgIA3CDL/qAvwEBXBwLvmUJBGNn69DgaKrIkDpp6BAb0cBrRPDtBld0f%2BYC5hSsfsAwBiq8haoGBq5YKC0FFxSVgxpeCOVcryaQ8howd48LSSANhtCAisL2IkfynDJAUikP5HBmSRGE2JnktpnSQDeIIL01AzMVFqPZRwTR2jdFGkGScLgFJinFN4GYogfzMQYwhbYouewS7yFhRXV6ugzCsrjTsTllyIkECib4/xrSw7BIDRwetnII0tIkTaxJdrTW8PSf2ThJSLQDwYRSSQlSS0hOaaI4NpMwYQ0kP2PYFJEicICFwS0MN/IsItJghp/qmkiOtZgsw5rhHZPEcQtYjKMjOEkEAA) (GCC fails 1/11 tests, MSVC fails 6/11 tests, Clang is fine).

Comment: _"lifetime extension mechanism is little-known and shouldn't be relied upon in the real world"_  - Perhaps a link to reasons or a hint about why would be good?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can't prove obscurity, but I can show compiler bugs: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zadxYYWs6 GCC miscompiles 1 case, MSVC miscompiles 5 and refuses to compile 1. Clang passes all of them.

Comment: That's ... wow! Making a note in the answer and referring to an example would be brilliant. It's a real world "why not - because".

Comment: @TedLyngmo Done. I've reported this to MSVC a ~year ago, and while I don't have a bug link at hand, the answer was a boilerplate boiling down to "this doesn't look very imporant to us".

Comment: Brilliant! I have had a few of those - and then 3-4 years later they all get solved. Presumably because that one person who has the "oh ..." reaction sees the backlog.